# Changing Bootstrap Button Color to make Facebook Block Button

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, less

I am creating a block level button on my signup page. My question is how can I override the color of the button for this specific button so that it become the blue that facebook buttons always are.

I am using Django, Python, Bootstrap & Less

Here is my code:

signin.html template:

```
<button type="button" class="btn-block" id="fb-button"><i class="fa fa-facebook"></i>Facebook</button>
```

app.less stylesheet:

```
#fb-button {
  color: #3b5998;
}
```

This isn't working my button is this weird white/gray color and not sure why. I have nothing else that I think is overriding the color. Why is this specific id selector not changing the color?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, this is what you want. 
fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/74x5975j/4/

```
#fb-button {
  color: white !important;
  background-color: #3b5998 !important;
  border-color: #3b5998 !important;
}
```

Comment: for some reason that doesnt work on my site. not sure why it stays the weird gray colour

Comment: Try adding it to the bottom of your HTML page like this `<style>#fb-button {
  color: white;
  background-color: #3b5998;
  border-color: #3b5998;
}</style>`

Comment: I suspect that it is getting overridden by something else in your css.

Comment: I don't see how anything else can be overriding it. There is literally like nothing there in my css file

Comment: even when I add it to the bottom of my html file the same thing happens

Comment: lol, then share your page. It can be the javascript or who knows what. one more try add !important to the colors, I udated it in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

use this
in your less

```
@btn-fb-color:#fff;
@btn-fb-bg:#3b5998;
@btn-fb-border:@btn-fb-bg;

.btn-fb {
  .button-variant(@btn-fb-color; @btn-fb-bg; @btn-fb-border);
}
```

Then change your html to:

```
<button type="button" class="btn-block btn-fb"><i class="fa fa-facebook"></i> Facebook</button>
```

Comment: This doesn't work for me either. The same gray color looking button remains :/

Comment: @Javier You may have other styles on your site taking precedence over the above styles. Use the DOM inspector and look at the styles being applied to your button

Comment: I only see this: button, input, optgroup, select, textarea {
  color: inherit;

Comment: nothing else useful in inspector I can find that may have to do with color

Comment: Working fiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/5wrn4pow/
Less must produce sth like this.
Maybe you are not building it or sth ??

Comment: @Javiar are you sure your app.less is included? try adding *{diplay:none!important;} or *{color:red!important;} or something else to see if you app.less is included